# Finding top directories sending out mail per day

Tags: ssh, terminal, cpanel, exim

I am trying to find out the top directories (cPanel accounts) sending out mail per day.

I have tried using the following code, which works, but this doesn't limit the results per day / date.

```
grep cwd /var/log/exim_mainlog | grep -v /var/spool | awk -F"cwd=" '{print $2}' | awk '{print $1}' | sort | uniq -c | sort -n
```

Is there anyway I can amend this code to show only the results of a specific date?

Answer (score 0):

If you'd like to filter by a specific date perhaps include the date string in your grep statement?

If you want to group by day, then use sed to strip the time part of the date and use `uniq -c` to count the occurrences of each day.